# Tips on quantum cryptography?

Tags: resource-request, cryptography

Can you please recommend some good papers on quantum cryptography? I really need to learn more about this topic (any tips will be very helpful).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start from this excellent intro course by Thomas Vidick and Stephanie Wehner, available in [Edx](https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-cryptography). Then take a look at some classic papers:

1. The one that started it all: https://core.ac.uk/reader/82447194.
2. The one that brought a whole new approach: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.661
3. The one that simplified it somewhat: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.68.3121

Also, assuming you are at the beginning, as Quantum Cryptography is an application of quantum information theory in general, read the bible for it too. Which is otherwise known as the [Nielsen and Chuang book](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf).